# Excluding Draft PRs from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I will like to be able to choose to only run Jenkins build on PRs who are not marked as draft. Is there currently a way to do that?

I found something like this: https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-branch-source-plugin/pull/416, but cannot seem to find any place in the Jenkins dashboard that will allow me to exclude draft PRs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [GitHub API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/pulls) allows you to view details of a PR and see if the PR is a draft:

Request:

```
curl \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \ 
  -H "Authorization: token <TOKEN>" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/pulls/PULL_NUMBER
```

Response:

```
{
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/pulls/1347",
  "id": 1,
  "node_id": "MDExOlB1bGxSZXF1ZXN0MQ==",
  ...
  "auto_merge": null,
  "draft": false, <---- This is what you want
  "merged": false,
  ...
  "deletions": 3,
  "changed_files": 5
}
```

You will have to modify the Jenkins job itself to perform this API call, parse the response and get the value of `draft`, and continue or abort the build depending on the value.